# Error running 'dev': java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Executable is not specified

Tags: javascript, java, gulp, phpstorm

After reinstalling PhpStorm 2019.3 EAP , now gulp tasks does not work. 
Error: `Error running 'dev': java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Executable is not specified`

Help me please[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with JetBrains Rider.  Whatever they changed, they messed things up.  Time for me to revert back to a stable version until they get this ironed out.

Comment: @PerryTew write to technical support JetBrains, if my solution did not help you.They answered me: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Java and uninstalling an entirely earlier version of phpstorm helped me. Installed php 2019.2

**UPDATE 9.11.2019:** also they answered me: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42270

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the option 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' option from the File menu.

Since PHPStorm caches all the results from your files (docker services, gulp/grun tasks, classes, makefiles, etc) something may have gotten stuck after the update, maybe you left PHPStorm open and it wasn't able to acquire the required permissions to delete a file that was being used by another process. Go figure.

It's also a good menu section to know. Whenever my Phpstorm starts acting up, I use the Invalidade Caches/Restart and it usually solves the problem.